# ag (the_silver_searcher) definition of hidden dir and including hidden dirs in search path

Tags: ag

The man does not define 'hidden' and 'ignored'. This probably means the 'hidden' is a file starting with a dot and 'ignored' is an entry in related ignore lists (.gitignore and .ignore).

However it is not clear if 'hidden' also includes hidden dirs. For example, `.config` dir is ignored even with `--hidden` option, but is included with `-u` option.

What is the rule for hidden dirs, if any? Are all hidden dirs ignored without `-u` option?

Comment: See also: [silver searcher ignore multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36601233/) and [Silver Searcher: Excluding files in vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37450771/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hidden files mean dotfiles. `ag` by default ignores hidden files (i.e. dotfiles). This includes any hidden file or directory, we use the `--hidden` argument to bypass that.

From the [man page](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md),

> --hidden
> Search hidden files. This option obeys ignored files.

Thus, it means any hidden file or directory (files within hidden directories in our case).

Using the unrestricted `-u` argument makes it search *everything*: binary files, hidden files and even ignoring .ignores, .gitignore etc.

> -u --unrestricted
> Search all files. This ignores .ignore, .gitignore, etc. It searches binary and hidden files as well.

This is the difference between them. I couldn't reproduce what you said:

> For example, .config dir is ignored even with --hidden option, but is
> included with -u option.

Placing a file in the folder `.config/README.md` and searching
using `--hidden` yielded the result for me. One scenario where it could happen for you is if your `.config` dir is added to your `.gitignore` file (a common setting) or any other ignore file. Thus `-u` will always work.

Further reading:

1. [Here is a good comment](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/24#issuecomment-45399931) I found in the old issue pertaining to this
   in the ag repository explaining the difference.
2. [How do I configure ag so that it will also search for files beginning with a "."?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689209/how-do-i-configure-ag-so-that-it-will-also-search-for-files-beginning-with-a) (unix.stackexchange).