# ag (the silver searcher) does not automatically search recursively

Tags: fzf, ag, vim-fzf

When performing `ag pattern` it only searches in the files in the current directory, even when providing `--depth NUM>1`. Performing `ag pattern ./**` looks in all subdirectories as well. I am currently using the `:Ag` command with fzf-vim which also only searches files in the current directory and not any subdirectories. I seem to recall ag searching recursively before, especially with `:Ag` without any customizations. Is it default behaviour to not search subdirectories for ag? All other fzf searches looks recursively.

I have tried different ag commands but expect `ag`/`:Ag` to search recursively by default.

Comment: Which version of `ag`? I have 2.2.0 and it definitely does recurse. Check whether any of the files in IGNORING FILES in the man page are affecting you.

Comment: Agree with @JoeP. I have 2.2.0 and mine searches recursively by default. Maybe ignoring/hidden could be the cause, see further at  [ag (the_silver_searcher) definition of hidden dir and including hidden dirs in search path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090628/) and related questions.